# Power Set of set containing the empty set and a set as an element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm just a little confused on the nuances of power sets. I'm looking for the power set of the following set: $\{\varnothing, a, \{a\}\}$

Comment: I am almost certain that this exactly question appeared before.

Comment: Can you find the power set of $\{x,y,z\}$? If so, do exactly the same thing. If necessary, temporarily let $x=\varnothing$, $y=a$, and $z=\{a\}$, then translate back when you’re done listing the subsets.

Comment: Compute the power set of $\{A,B,C\}$ and then just replace $A=\emptyset$, $B=a$ and $C=\{a\}$ no mysteries or nuance here.

Comment: @Asaf: you're think about a question about deja vu. I think I made this post before...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: we were typing at the same time, no intention to replicate your sound suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps the point of the above advice (which is excellent) is that the empty set is *something*, is isn't *nothing*. It *contains* nothing, but that is a different matter.

Comment: Thank you Sergio Parreiras and Brian M. Scott, I was just afraid of the mysteries.

Comment: I'm sure Yogi Berra had something to say about power sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 
$\mathfrak{P}(M)=\{ \emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{a\}, \{\{a\}\}, \{\emptyset, a\}, \{\emptyset, \{a\}\}, \{a, \{a\}\},  \{\emptyset, a,\{a\}\}    \}$ where $M=\{\emptyset, a,\{a\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solve such problems.

First off, keep in mind that for a set $S$ containing $n$ distinct elements, where $n$ is a nonnegative integer, $|\wp(S)| = 2^n $.
For your set $M = \{\emptyset, a,\{a\}\}$, M contains 3 distinct elements, therefore it should have $2^3 = 8$ distinct subsets.

Ok, now when you are listing the subsets of a set, start off by writing down the empty set $\emptyset$, and the set itself $\{\emptyset, a,\{a\}\}$.

Next, write out each element in the set as a subset of its own, that is $\{\emptyset\}, \{a\}$ and  $\{\{a\}\}$. That takes care of 5 subsets so we have 3 left.

Finally, start making different pairs of each elements, that is $\{\emptyset, a\}, \{\emptyset, \{a\}\}$ and $\{a, \{a\}\}$.

Putting it all together:

$\wp(M)= \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{a\}, \{\{a\}\}, \{\emptyset, a\}, \{\emptyset, \{a\}\}, \{a, \{a\}\},  \{\emptyset, a,\{a\}\}\}$.